# Java pattern with word boundary doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I created a quite simple regexp in Java:

```
Pattern polar = Pattern.compile("\\bPOLAR\\.\\b");
assertEquals(true, polar.matcher("My String POLAR. other string").find()); <=== this fails!
```

I want to find if there is the word "POLAR." in my string. I'm doing something wrong in my regexp but I don't see what.

Do you have some hint?

Comment: There is no word boundary after dot (non-word). You can use: `"\\bPOLAR\\.\\B"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no word boundary after dot (non-word character).

You can use this regex:

```
\bPOLAR\.\B
```

`\B` asserts position where `\b` does not match.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNSXxV/1)

In Java:

```
final Pattern polar = Pattern.compile( "\\bPOLAR\\.\\B" );
```

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to be a regex? [`String::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) seems apt for this.

```
String str = "My String POLAR. other string";
System.out.println(str.contains("POLAR."));
```

Output:

> true

Comment: OP wrote `if there is the word "POLAR."` so OP wants to match dot and complete word `POLAR`

Comment: But now it will return true for `WHITEPOLAR.BEAR` also.

Comment: @anubhava fair enough - I could add spaces in too but maybe regex was the right tool after all :)